# API Documentation for vuetify component v-treeview of version v1.3.x

Tags: vuetify.js

Where can we can get the doc link of vuetify 1.3.x version ?

As I am getting one query, i have used `<v-treeview />` component of vuetify with the props following below:

```html
<v-treeview :open="open" :items="categoryItems" v-model="selectedCategory" selectable dense open-on-click selectionType="independent" return-object />
```

I want the v-model data to be an array of object but instead it is returning only id in array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where i can get vuetify 1.3.15 documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a ticket about the documentation server for v1.x being down (probably permanently) check here for more info: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12042

Here's the documentation for 1.5 you can probably find what you are looking for there: https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start

- for v-treeview: https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview

You can switch to an earlier version from the dropdown in the top right corner but as noted the archive server for older documentation is down